# What is the problem that occurs in the BroadcastReceiver onReceiveMethod? How to solve this problem?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

What is the problem that occurs in the BroadcastReceiver onReceiveMethod? How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The inner class:

```
new BroadcastReceiver() { }
```

does not have access to the doSomeTask() method since the doSomeTask() method is defined in the MainActivity class. Therefore, when you call doSomeTask() inside of:

```
if (intent.getAction ...) {
    doSomeTask();
}
```

You see an error